# Alfresco activiti workflow initiator - No QName prefix, why?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

Most of the Alfresco properties will have specific QName like, `cm:title, cm:name, bpm:assignee, bpm:assignees` etc.

When I looked the workflow initiator, it is referred like initiator and there is no specific QName prefixed it.

And somewhere in Java code, the initiator is referred like,

```
QName QNAME_INITIATOR = QName.createQName(NamespaceService.DEFAULT_URI, "initiator");
```

Is there any specific reason, the initiator does not have QName ?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco node properties are defined as a QName because they are defined with a namespace (or namespace prefix) and a property name. This is how they are stored in the Alfresco database tables.

The initiator of a workflow is not an alfresco property of a node, it is a variable(property) of a workflow instance. Workflow variables and task variables are stored in the activiti database tables.

That is why they do not have a namespace prefix, and hence no QName.